# C#. Checking a SQL Data Adapter for certain values

Tags: c#, sql, dataadapter

I have a database table and I am querying this table to check if a value already exists (for a login application).

I have a data adapter, but I do not know how to check if the data adapter contains the value I am looking for...

Here is the c#:

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Employee;Integrated Security=true";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
  {
     SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT UName FROM EVUSERS WHERE UName = '" + userName + "'", connection);
     da.Fill(dt);

     //this message displays proving the adapter contains values
     if(da != null)
       {
          MessageBox.Show("name exists");
       }
     }
```

I just would like to know how I can say something like

```
if (da contains username)  { do something }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to use the table's  `Rows.Count` property.

But you should really use sql-parameters to prevent sql-injection!

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT UName FROM EVUSERS WHERE UName = @UName", connection);
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UName", userName);
da.Fill(dt);

if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("name exists");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

- I am working with a Data Table and I want to use SqlDataAdapter to retrieve data with a search query. However, I want to include '%' signs before and after the parameters.

```
    public DataTable Search(string parameter)
            {
                string query = "Select * From MyContacts where name like @parameter or family like @parameter";
                SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connection);
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection);
                adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter", "%" + parameter + "%");
                DataTable data = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(data);
                return data;
            }
```

Comment: I’m confused. Is this an answer? Or a new question?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35650675)